# How correctly map such data in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I had string with id: `"1,2,3,4".`
I need to get array:

```
1 => Post::whereId(1)->get()->created_at
2 => Post::whereId(2)->get()->created_at
3 => Post::whereId(3)->get()->created_at
4 => Post::whereId(4)->get()->created_at
```

I try this:

```
$postMap = collect($item->posts_id)->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
            return [
                $item->posts_id => Post::whereId($item->postss_id)->first()->crated_at,
            ];
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `pluck()` method like this:

```
$array = Post::whereIn('id', explode(',', $arrayString))->pluck('created_at', 'id');
```